# Keep only the earliest occurence of overlapping data

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data set with factor variables obs, date, group ID, owner ID, damage type, and appt type.

Sample Data:

```
 obs   Date GroupID Owner ID    Damage Type Type
 1   5/8/2012   268dun56    125 front   Initial
 2   6/28/2012  924bndg32   126 driver front    Completed
 3   5/1/2015   963pkj23    127 passenger rear  Completed
 4   3/25/2016  9647kjh25   128 windshield  Initial
 5   3/26/2016  9647kjh25   128 windshield  Initial
```

Based on this, I know that obs 5 and 6 are the same vehicle because group id and owner id are unique identifiers. I would like to remove all repeated entries except for the earliest occurrence but am unsure of how to do that. The actual data set is from a car dealership for over 3 years so manually removing rows is not an option. 
I've tried several methods of removing duplicated entries but, since the entries aren't completely identical, nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `duplicated` on just the GroupID and OwnerID columns.

```
duplicated(df[,3:4])
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

df = df[!duplicated(df[,3:4]),]
df
  obs      Date   GroupID OwnerID     DamageType      Type
1   1  5/8/2012  268dun56     125          front   Initial
2   2 6/28/2012 924bndg32     126   driver front Completed
3   3  5/1/2015  963pkj23     127 passenger rear Completed
4   4 3/25/2016 9647kjh25     128     windshield   Initial
```

Comment: Depending one what's meant by "first occurrence", the date may need to be considered before `duplicated()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::slice` to select only the first row after grouping on `GroupID` and `Owner ID`. I would suggest first `arrange` your data on `Date` so that you always get the oldest data(first occurred data).

The solution will be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(GroupID, Owner.ID) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  slice(1) %>% as.data.frame()
#   obs       Date   GroupID Owner.ID    Damage.Type      Type
# 1   1 2012-05-08  268dun56      125          front   Initial
# 2   2 2012-06-28 924bndg32      126   driver front Completed
# 3   3 2015-05-01  963pkj23      127 passenger rear Completed
# 4   4 2016-03-25 9647kjh25      128     windshield   Initial
```

**Data:**

```
df<-read.table(text="
obs   Date     GroupID 'Owner ID'    'Damage Type' Type
1   5/8/2012   268dun56    125 front   Initial
2   6/28/2012  924bndg32   126 'driver front'    Completed
3   5/1/2015   963pkj23    127 'passenger rear'  Completed
4   3/25/2016  9647kjh25   128 windshield  Initial
5   3/26/2016  9647kjh25   128 windshield  Initial",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
```